# Purpose of Xor Linked List?

Tags: performance, memory, data-structures, xor, low-level

I stumbled on a Wikipedia article about the [Xor linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list), and it's an interesting bit of trivia, but the article seems to imply that it occasionally gets used in real code.  I'm curious what it's good for, since I don't see why it makes sense even in severely memory/cache constrained systems:

- The main advantage of a regular doubly linked list is the ability to insert or delete elements from the middle of the list given only a pointer to the node to be deleted/inserted after.  This can't be done with an xor-linked list.
- If one wants O(1) prepending or O(1) insertion/removal while iterating then singly linked lists are good enough and avoid a lot of code complexity and caveats with respect to garbage collection, debugging tools, etc.
- If one doesn't need O(1) prepending/insertion/removal then using an array is probably more efficient in both space and time.  Even if one only needs efficient insertion/removal while iterating, arrays can be pretty good since the insertion/removal can be done while iterating.

Given the above, what's the point?  Are there any weird corner cases where an xor linked list is actually worthwhile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from saving memory, it allows for O(1) reversal, while still supporting all the other destructive update operations efficienctly, like

- `concat`ing two lists destructively in O(1)
- `insertAfter`/`insertBefore` in O(1), when you only have a reference to the node and its successor/predecessor (which differs slightly from standard doubly linked lists)
- `remove` in O(1), also with a reference to either the successor or predecessor.

I don't think the memory aspect is really important, since for most scenarios where you might use a XOR list, you can use a singly-linked list instead.

Answer (score 2):

It is about saving memory. I had a situation where my data structure was 40 bytes. The memory manager aligned things on a 16 byte boundary, so each allocation was 48 bytes; regardless of the fact that I only needed 40. By using xor chain list, I was able to eliminate 8 bytes and drop my data structure size down to 32 bytes. Now, I can fit 2 nodes in the 64 byte pipeline cache at the same time. So, I was able to reduce memory usage, and improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Its purpose is (or more precisely *was*) just to save memory.

With a xor-linked-list you can do anything you can do with a ordinary doubly-linked list. The only difference is that you have to decode the `previous` and `next` memory addresses from the xor-ed pointer for each node every time you need them.